# Export passwords from Chrome 62, failsafe way?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, passwords, export

I checked several answers that were posted on here, but somehow nothing seems to work. I'm using Chrome version 62.0.3202.89 and I want to export my passwords in order to reinstall Chrome, since I can't update it anymore.

1. Copy and Paste from `chrome://settings/passwords` doesn't work. It pastes blank fields for the passwords, even if you made them visible with entering your password.
2. The icon that is supposed to be there to export my passwords isn't there.
   `chrome://flags/` -> `#password-import-export` is set to "Enabled" and I restarted the browser after resetting it, but that didn't change anything.
3. I downloaded "ChromePass" and started it, but it didn't show any passwords. Maybe I am using it wrong?
4. Apparently you can sync your chrome browser with your Google-Account and then export the passwords from there. There is supposed to be a "Profile" Icon on the upper right corner of the chrome browser, but I don't see that anywhere. I have the three dots (...) menu with things like "new tab", "history", "print", "advanced tools", "settings" and so on, but nothing like a "Profile" Icon.
5. I copied the "Login Data" file from  `C:\Users\name\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default`, but I read that it doesn't store the passwords anymore and you can't just copy it, or something like that.

The only remaining option that I see would be external password-managers like LastPass, KeePass and what else might be out there, but I haven't tried that yet.

Does anyone know another way before I try my luck with LastPass? (Beside manually writing down each password.)

If not, then I will try LastPass and see if that works. Thank you for any suggestions.

Comment: Is this PC connected to an Active Directory domain by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound I had to look up what that is. If I understand correctly it is if you have something that runs on Windows Server OS in your network?
Then no, my PC isn't connected to something like that.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using such an old version of Chrome release more than 2 years ago?